# How to transform a complex,nested json into csv

Tags: json, csv, command-line, jq

Here's the input json

```
{
    "step": 1,
    "inputs": {
        "first_input": {
            "file_id": "xxx"
        }
        "second_input": 3
    }
}
{
    "step": 2,
    "inputs": {
        "my_first_arg": {
            "file_id": "yyy"
        }
        "my_second_arg": 0
    }
}
```

The desired csv file is

```
1,first_input,"xxx"
1,second_input,3
2,my_first_arg:"yyy"
2,my_second_arg,0
```

The challenge here is that each `inputs` field contains a dictionary with different key names and the different types of values. Basically I want the value of the `step` field, all keys of `inputs`, and the children nodes of values of `inputs`, but having related data stay in the same row in the csv.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To produce an array of the desired values:

```
.step as $step
| .inputs
| to_entries[]
| .key as $key
| [$step, .key]
  + (.value | if type=="object" then to_entries[] | [.key, .value] else [$key, .] end)
```

Tacking on `@csv` at the end would produce CSV values, with numbers unquoted.
Using the -r command-line option and making minor corrections to the sample input would produce:

```
1,"first_input","file_id","xxx"
1,"second_input","second_input",3
2,"my_first_arg","file_id","yyy"
2,"my_second_arg","my_second_arg",0
```

If you really want the output as indicated in the Q, then conditionally add the quotation marks (`"\""`) where desired, and use `join(",")` instead of `@csv`.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using python and it's json module to parse the json, then you can do pretty much whatever you want. Here is an example that does pretty much what you want. So, i'd say, get it to spit it out exactly the way you want, change it to load the json from file, change the csv output from StringIO to an actual file, and you are pretty much done.

```
import json, csv, io

json_str = '[{"step":1,"inputs":{"first_input":{"file_id":"xxx"},"second_input":3}},{"step":2,"inputs":{"my_first_arg":{"file_id":"yyy"},"my_second_arg":0}}]'

def value(jsn):
    if not isinstance(jsn, dict):
        return jsn
    return next(iter(jsn))

jsndata = json.loads(json_str)
csvdata = io.StringIO()
csvwriter = csv.writer(csvdata)
for i in jsndata:
    step = i['step']
    for key in i['inputs']:
        val = value(i['inputs'][key])
        csvwriter.writerow([step, key, val]);

print(csvdata.getvalue())
```